# Which version is the most appropriate for the name of an institution?

Tags: nouns

It is a question of conversion or translation from Chinese into English.

Recently in China, there are many vocational institutions now which are sponsored by the government and offer higher or tertiary education to students who fail to get admitted into the traditional academic institutions (colleges or universities).

But they meet the same problem, that is, they have different versions for the same name in Chinese.

For example, there are such schools in the field of transport across China, with names in Chinese nearly the same, but with different translated names in English.

*Guangxi* Vocational and Technical College of Communications

*Hebei* Jiaotong Vocational and Technical College

*Shanghai* Communications Polytechnic

*Zhejiang* Institute of Communications

*Shanxi* Traffic Vocational and Technical College

*Ningxia* Polytechnic

*Shaanxi* College of Communication Technology**

**Note**: The above names in Chinese are the same, except the italic part indicating the place where this institute is located

So, which version is the most appropriate? Or is there other version?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about translation inconsistencies, and not about learning English.

Comment: @user3169 Learning a foreign language means translation plays an important role in the learning, otherwise how can you begin your learning when you do not know a syllable of that language? English is now a foreign language, not a mother tongue to me,OK? When you have time to find fault with the question, why not try to  give your opinion but not say something that discourage a hard learner, thank you very much.

Comment: The thing is, proper names are just that. The different names you listed were chosen by someone to reflect what education that school offers, using existing English language schools as examples (rather than by some kind of translation). The common words are technical, vocational and communications, but how to arrange them in a title has no right or wrong.

Comment: You ask us to decide on a matter of style. This has nothing to do with learning the English language. Even more, it's hard to see the importance to Chinese people of the words used in the English-language translation of the name of a Chinese trade school! What difference can it make to them? Use the Chinese name!

Comment: @P.E.Dant Sir, you cannot be more wrong in your answer. It is very important for people in China and elsewhere to have a proper name in English because now the globe is no more than a village. If English language were a dead language like Latin or a man-made language like Esparando, I would not trouble myself to ask native speakers of English in this forum.If you are such a native speaker, would you accept misuse of your mother tongue by non-natives?

Comment: @user3169 Do you imply that we can use English as we see fit regardless of the grammar or other rules? And still this type of English so used by us can be recognized and accepted by you without making any misunderstanding?

Comment: In answer to your question: no, it is of no importance me to what English name is used by a trade school in Shanxi, and deciding on the translation has nothing to do with learning English. If they were to open a school in the U.S., I might care what they call it. (As an aside, If the world were truly a "village", you could visit any website you want, such as the **[N. Y. Times](http://nytimes.com)**,  **[CNN](http://cnn.com)**, or **[YouTube](http://youtube.com)**.)

Comment: KIndly be advised to ask any Chinese living in the mainland of China, whether they could legally visit the websites you listed or not. So when you feel overfilled with your stomach, don't jeer at those who do not have enough food to fill the same vacuum. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: You misunderstand my comment. It was intended only to point out that the world is not a "village". If it were, every resident of the village would enjoy the same freedoms. In our country, we too were once oppressed by a cruel ruler who told us what we could read, write, and publish. We overcame that ruler and fought for and won our freedom. So may it come to pass for all peoples!

Comment: @P.E.Dant Village here means the accessibility becomes easy, not necessarily everybody enjoys the same thing, and it is obviously impossible even for twins to enjoy the same thing. But you are right we should fight back the oppressor if there is really one existing, whether in the form of a real dictor as Kim Jung Un in North Korea, or in the form of a democrat as Donald Trump. The fight could not be made possible without the common weapon, --which in my opinion, is English. After learning good English, we know what really happen in the world, not to be deceived by bad guys.

Comment: You don't understand. Our President is elected by the people, not chosen by a bunch of old men meeting in secret. We have the vote to oppose or support any elected office holder. Those under the dictatorship of Winnie the Pooh have no vote. Language, be it English or any other, plays no part. Mere talk cannot overthrow a tyrant. It takes fighting, not talking, as it did for us in 1776.

Comment: We Chinese kept a closer watch on the presidential election in your country than in ours, because yours is more twisting and interesting, and ours is simply a joke. I watched the reality show made by Mr. Trump 12 years ago, i knew this guy very well. He would not reserve his like or dislike for anybody's sake. Regarding Winnie the Pooh, I only know it is the hero of the cartoon Super Sleuth, but why  it has something to do with a dictor is really beyond me. As to the fighting, you are right, but without a common language, how can we start the fight and ensure not to kill friends in it?

Answer (score 0):

*Zhejiang Institute of Communications*

This sounds natural. And it could be "Zhejiang Institute of Communication Techniques" or "Zhejiang Institute of Communication Technology."

However, other names you mentioned are possible, too.

Comment: Please if you could give more reason, it would be much better

Comment: It's simple. "Institute of XX" is a common way. Institute of physics, Institute of medicine..I think yours can mean "Institute of IT communication", too, if possible. We have many ways and alternatives.